# Samsung Tab S2 not respecting manifest screenOrientation

Tags: android, screen-orientation, android-sensors, landscape

I have an Activity that is meant to be displayed in landscape. Ideally I want to support either direction of landscape. In my manifest I've set this on my Activity:

```
android:screenOrientation="sensorLandscape"
```

Which has worked fine in all my experience in the past. But this device seems to decide sometimes that portrait orientation is allowed. It will rotate to all 4 orientations (landscape/reverseLandscape, and portrait/reversePortrait).

If I set it like this:

```
android:screenOrientation="landscape"
```

it works correctly. Also if I disable screen rotation then it works correctly. However both of these options leave me with no reverseLandscape.

I've also tried requesting the orientation to be set in Java code:

```
setRequestedOrientation (ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_SENSOR_LANDSCAPE);
```

This does not seem to make any difference in the behavior.

Is this a known issue on Samsung devices? and is there any workaround to get the device to respect my sensorLandscape orientation setting?